# Ionic Cordova build android —prod —release Mac error con android bulld tools instalado

Tags: android-studio, ionic4, vscode, macos

Necesito POR FAVOR ayuda con 'ionic build cordova android --prod --release ... Cuando lo corro me tira el siguiente error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 28s
/Users/sebastianloguzzo/Desktop/myselfHotel/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/sebastianloguzzo/Desktop/myselfHotel/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Probé  de todo: ya elimine la platform y volvi a agregarla. confirguré .bash_profile con:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Users/sebastianloguzzo/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

luego haciendo source .bash_profile y el printenv PATH me arroja corrrecatemnte lo que puse ... pero en VSCODE cuando corro el comando para generar el apk me sigue dando el error. Trabajo en macOS Catalina
Ya lei todos los blogs posibles pero no encuentro solución

Comment: El JDK instalado de java tiene que coincidir especificamente con la version 8 y no las versiones mas nuevas de java, tambien decir que si tienes mas de un Java instalado habra conflictos. esto porque segun la documentacion oficial de ionic, desafortunadamente cordova no es compatible con las ultimas versiones de java.

Comment: Claro! Yo instalé el 1.8 y seleccioné para que se utilice el 1.8. Entonces de arrojarme el error de Java, pero me sigue saliendo el error de android tools a pesar de tener instalado el android studio y el tools superior a la version 19